# Unable to find resource ID when building fragment with Robolectric

Tags: android, android-fragments, robolectric

Using Robolectric 3.3.2 I am trying to build a fragment and attach it to an activity. I tried `Robolectric.buildFragment(MyFragment.class, MyActivity.class).create()` but I get exception `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x1 in packages [android, com.my.package.for.android]`.

I also tried building the activity and fragment separately and attach the fragment using the fragment manager but it seems that the fragment is automatically attached to a dummy activity so I cannot attach it to my activity.

Minimalistic example:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT, manifest = "./src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void WorkingTest1() throws Exception {
        Robolectric.buildFragment(MyFragment.class).create();
    }

    @Test
    public void WorkingTest2() throws Exception {
        Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class).create();
    }

    @Test
    public void FailingTest() throws Exception {
        Robolectric.buildFragment(MyFragment.class, MyActivity.class).create();
    }

    public static class MyActivity extends Activity {
    }

    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a root Activity frame already defined for my Activity, so I can supply that for the FragmentManager transaction inside Robolectric's FragmentController:

```
Robolectric
    .buildFragment(MyFragment.class, MyActivity.class)
    .create(R.id.my_activity_frame);
```

In my Activity:

```
setContentView(R.id.my_activity_frame);
```

Comment: I was unware that you could specify the id in the `create` method. This solves the problem, thanks! I realize now that I had read the wrong javadoc on Google (I read javadoc for org.robolectric.util.FragmentController instead of org.robolectric.android.controller.FragmentController).

Comment: Note though that the correct signature is `create(int contentViewId, Bundle bundle)` :)

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation I did find a workaround (albeit ugly). It seems Robolectric expects a ViewGroup with id 1 in the activity view hierarchy. The solution I found was to write `findViewById(android.R.id.content).setId(1);` in the activity's `onCreate(Bundle)` (or add a new ViewGroup and set it's id to 1 programmatically). This seems like a terrible thing to to in production code though so I made a test subclass.

```
public class MyTestableActivity extends MyActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        findViewById(android.R.id.content).setId(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running with default RobolectricTestRunner , make sure your res/ folder is at the same location as AndroidManifest.xml.
I got the issue resolved with something like

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = "./path/AndroidManifest.xml") 
public class FragmentTest{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by doing a variation of other answers:

```
Robolectric
    .buildFragment(YourFragment.class, Activity.class)
    .create(android.R.id.content, new Bundle());
```

Note that you can also substitute Activity.class for a static inner test-only YourTestActivity.class as well.